# php memory limit issue during image resize after image upload

Tags: php, image, image-uploading, image-resizing, memory-limit

Hy, I have a page where a user can upload an image (one at a time, the second upload overwrites the first one).

When someone chooses an image which is more than 5 MB, the script will upload the image but it will then run another script that will resize the image to make it smaller.

So, i get the image size, and set the maximum size like so:

```
$size = $_FILES["userImage"]["size"]
$maxSize = 5000000 //this should be 5 MB, right?
```

then, I move the image to a folder with this line

```
move_uploaded_file( $tmpName, "../user_img/".$sessionId."/".$sessionId."_img.".$type);
```

and in the end, I want to resize the image if it is above 5 MB

```
if($size > $maxSize){
include('resizeImage2.php'); 
//indicate which file to resize (can be any type jpg/png/gif/etc...)
$file = "../user_img/".$sessionId."/".$sessionId."_img.".$type;

//indicate the path and name for the new resized file
$resizedFile = $file;

//call the function (when passing path to pic)
//smart_resize_image($file, null, 1200, 0, true, $resizedFile, true, false, 100 );
//call the function (when passing pic as string)
smart_resize_image(null , file_get_contents($file), 1200 , 0 , true , $resizedFile , true , false ,100 );
    }
```

the resizeImage2.php is something I found on the internet at this [address](https://github.com/Nimrod007/PHP_image_resize/blob/master/smart_resize_image.function.php)

and the problem occurs when I try to upload an image from my PC that is 7MB, and 10004 x 10967 in resolution. I get an error

Allowed memory size of 62914560 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 40016 bytes)

I know i can change the memory limit in php.ini, but i was wondering if there is another way to make this work? Are any of my scripts badly written?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Try this put it at header on page-

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit','16M');
?>
```

Comment: I know I can set the memory limit but is it the right way? There's also a problem that my real server (i'm currently working on xampp) has my site limited 64 MB in memory limit

Comment: Read this http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/777/solve-php-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-8388608-bytes-exhausted-tried/

Comment: thnx, but it didn't help me. I know i can set the value in php.ini but I am looking for other ways.. maybe my scripts are baddly written and there's something to do there. This way, I may increase my memory limit to 2GB.. and then what?

Answer (score 2):

You can increase this uploaded files limit in your `php.ini` file, by adding or updating a line similar to the following:

```
memory_limit = 128M
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two tricks to increase the max upload size in php

Increasing file upload size by `.htaccess`

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
```

Increasing file upload size by `php.ini` files

```
upload_max_filesize = 10M
```